# accidently i enable mp3 play from server in Opera, how can i disable it.?

Tags: music, opera-mini

While downloading a song from song website i marked it as "Play from Opera" Now instead of downloading the song, it plays from server. How can i disable it in m
y Samsung Galaxy Y duos. Andro 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Clear data for both Opera browser and the app you tried to download the song from. Launch again - it should work fine.

Comment: Clear Defaults, not data.